# TableLayout, android:layout_weight, and include

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout with 6 included layouts in a `TableLayout`. I want to do this in landscape mode, because a `ScrollView` would be awkward in my scenario.

I have a 48dp-high horizontal layout, which contains a square `ImageView`, a `SeekBar` with full weight, and a square `ImageButton`. I set the drawables for the `ImageView` in Java.

In the main layout, I use an `include` for each one and I am trying to even out the columns, because they only take up half the screen, by the way this is an activity with `Theme.Holo.Dialog` as its theme.

However, when I run the app, **I get a 40-60% unbalanced view**. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Part of **layout-land/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ... >
...
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/systemToast"/>
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/ringerToast"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/notifyToast"/>
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/mediaToast"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/alarmToast"/>
        <include android:layout_weight="1" layout="@layout/toast_item" android:id="@+id/inCallToast"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-land/toast_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="48dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_audio_alarm"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:maxHeight="1000dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/schedules"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have `android:layout_weight`, but I didn't seem `android:weightSum`.

I would suggest you have `android:weightSum="2"` so that your two objects that have `android:layout_weight="1"` will distribute evenly.

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

> If there are three text fields and two of them declare a
> weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field
> without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
> its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space
> remaining after all three fields are measured.
>
> If the third field is
> then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more
> important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining
> space, while the first two share the rest equally.

Comment: In TableLayout or TableRow?

Comment: Try TableRow. Although, I noticed you have weight="0" in your LinearLayout for `toast_item`. That's basically equivalent to `wrap_content`. I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I never would have guessed that the `android:weightSum` would do that. I rarely use `TableLayout`, and `LinearLayout` never has to do that. Thanks. :)